# I want to use torify with youtube-dl but it gives me an error

Tags: tor

I want to use torify with youtube-dl but it is give me an error whereas tor browser is working

`/usr/bin/torify: torsocks not found in your PATH.  Perhaps it isn't installed?  (tsocks is no longer supported, for security reasons.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packaging system says:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ apt-cache search torsocks
tor - anonymizing overlay network for TCP
torsocks - use SOCKS-friendly applications with Tor
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

So, assuming you're using Ubuntu,

```
dpkg -l torsocks
```

will show you if it's installed;

```
sudo apt install torsocks
```

will install `torsocks`;

```
dpkg -L torsocks
```

will list the directories and files in the package.